# Location Services not returning close places

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I'm using a code which I will post after this to return the closest places based on what the user types in a UITextField using a natural language query. I store all the places in an array and that pass that array to the next scene (a UITableViewController) in prepareForSegue. Than I use the array to load all the places. On the simulator, it shows all the default locations that Apple has which makes sense. But then, I test it out on a real iPhone and despite enabling location services for the app, I still get default locations. I tried again and again but I could not get actual results. It worked once a few weeks ago, but since then it has stopped. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
- (void) performSearch {
    NSLog(_searchLabel.text);
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request =
    [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];

    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _searchLabel.text;
    _foundPlaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _foundPlacesD = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //NSLog(_place);
    MKLocalSearch *search =
    [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse
                                         *response, NSError *error) {
        if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
            NSLog(@"No Matches");
        else{
            for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
            {
                NSString *n = item.name;

                [_foundPlaces addObject:n];

                NSLog(n);
                MKDirectionsRequest *dr = [MKDirectionsRequest new];
                MKMapItem *source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
                [dr setSource:source];
                [dr setDestination:item];
                MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:dr];
                [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *mresponse, NSError *error) {
                    if(mresponse.routes.count == 0){
                        NSLog(@"No routes");
                    }
                    else{
                        for(MKRoute *route in mresponse.routes){
                            CLLocationDistance d = route.distance/1000;
                            NSString *dText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g kilometers", d];
                            [_foundPlacesD addObject:dText];
                            NSLog(dText);
                        }
                    }
                }];

            }
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"locationResults" sender:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed it. The error was that the segue was being performed outside the completion, when it should be performed inside.